# MS Fakes in TFS VS Build Test-step

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, build, installation, microsoft-fakes

How to enable MS Fakes generating in TFS 2017 VS Build Test-step without installation of Visual Studio on build server?

I know there is a [way by copying some files from developer machine to the build Server](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44928697/2336304) but it doesn't seem right.

There is also "VS Build Tools 2017" that distributes some targets and references for build process without full VS stand alone installed, but it still doesn't include Fakes support!

Is there any package for that so I could install it without silly per file copying, wihtout VS and my own licence on server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afraid there is no way to bypass this, you have to install visual studio and   need an **Enterprise** edition , unfortunately.

[image]

Have a look at this article in the Test section: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/compare/ . If you could simply add some free packages, there is no need to restrict users only use visual studio enterprise edition for ***Microsoft Fakes (Unit Test Isolation)*** support.